# JS Script crashes after temporaryURL is created with livewire

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

Does anyone know, How to resolve this issue of the crashed javascript script?

I am using 2 checkboxes to load some DOM.

1st checkbox is to expand textarea with the CKEditor script which is loaded with the JS but I have a wire model to send data to the controller.

Here is HTML for 1st checkbox:

```
<div class="form-group mt-25 d-flex flex-row">
                            <label class="checkbox-container form-group__label">
                                {{ __('Extended description') }}
                                <input type="checkbox" name="extended-description-checkbox" id="extended-description-checkbox" class="checkbox">
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group mt-25 cke d-none" id="extended-description-checkbox-div">
                            <label class="form-group__label" for="extended-description">{{ __('Extended description') }}</label>
                            <textarea wire:ignore.self wire:model.debounce.250ms.defer="extendedDescription" name="extended-description" id="extended-description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                        </div>
```

2nd checkbox is also handled with the JS and has a temporary URL method since the expanded DOM element should contain uploaded images for the gallery.

Here is HTML of the 2nd checkbox:

```
<div class="form-group mt-25 d-flex flex-row">
                            <label class="checkbox-container form-group__label">
                                {{ __('Use default images') }}
                                <input type="checkbox" name="use-default-images" id="use-default-images" class="checkbox">
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="d-none" id="use-default-images-div">
                            <div class="form-group mt-25">
                                <label class="form-group__label">{{ __('Service images') }}</label>
                                <div class="form-group__uploaded-images">
                                    @if ($additionalImages)
                                        @foreach($additionalImages as $image)
                                            <img src="{{ $image->temporaryUrl() }}" alt="Temporary image">
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="custom-file ml-auto">
                                <button type="button" class="ml-auto styled-link">{{ __('Add images') }}</button>
                                <div class="row mt-25">
                                    <div class="col-4 col-md-8"></div>
                                    <div class="col-8 col-md-4">
                                        <input wire:ignore.self wire:model.defer="additionalImages" type="file" multiple>
                                        @error('images.*') {{ $message }} @enderror
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here are the scripts for expanding of the both DOM elements:

```
const extendedCheckbox = document.querySelector('#extended-description-checkbox');
    const extendedDiv = document.querySelector('#extended-description-checkbox-div');

    extendedCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(extendedCheckbox.checked) {
            extendedDiv.classList.remove('d-none');
        } else {
            extendedDiv.classList.add('d-none');
        }
    });

    const defaultImagesCheckbox = document.querySelector('#use-default-images');
    const defaultImagesDiv = document.querySelector('#use-default-images-div');

    defaultImagesCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(defaultImagesCheckbox.checked) {
            defaultImagesDiv.classList.remove('d-none');
        } else {
            defaultImagesDiv.classList.add('d-none');
        }
    });
```

Comment: When you say that JS crashes, what do you mean exactly? Which error do you get?

Comment: @Qirel When I upload images at the second DOM my CKEditor crashes

Comment: Aha, then you'll need `wire:ignore` - see https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#ignoring-dom-changes

Comment: I have used it :D "<textarea wire:ignore.self wire:model.debounce.2......"

Comment: Think you can't use the self-modifier